# cmd.Run() hangs forever in golang on Macos when the screen is locked/off

Tags: macos, go, osascript

I am running a golang app on Macos. It has some codes like the following:

```
for {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/osascript", "-e", `display dialog "hello" with title "hello"`)
    err := cmd.Run()
}
```

It works fine if I don't lock the screen (when the screen is always on). But the code `err := cmd.Run()` will hang forever if the screen is locked and off when that line executes. When I unlock the screen (turn it on), the `for` loop just hangs there forever and will never continue its execution.

I am not sure if this issue belongs to golang or how MacOS handles osascript. Can anyone please tell me how to workaround it? Thanks a lot.

PS: I use the same code in Linux and replace `/usr/bin/osascript` to `/usr/bin/xmessage` and this always works fine without any problems even if the screen is locked/off in Linux.

**Edited:**

My solution, use chrome instead:

```
cmd := exec.Command(`/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`, "-new-window", "/path/hello.html")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be related to how MacOS puts processes in idle when the screen locks. It makes the `osasscript`child process never finish execution and block the for loop.

One thing you can do is run the command with a timeout context. I have tried and it works. Execution will resume when the screen is unlocked and timeout expires.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)

        // run your command with a timeout
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
        cmd := exec.CommandContext(
            ctx,
            "/usr/bin/osascript",
            "-e",
            `display dialog "hello" with title "hello"`,
        )

        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        // don't forget to cancel your context to avoid context leak
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a timeout you can check if the screen is locked before trying to call display dialog.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)

        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
        cmd := exec.CommandContext(
            ctx,
            "python",
            "-c",
            "import sys,Quartz; d=Quartz.CGSessionCopyCurrentDictionary(); print d",
        )

        var err error
        var b []byte
        if b, err = cmd.CombinedOutput(); err != nil {
            cancel()
            continue
        }
        cancel()

        // if screen is not locked
        if !strings.Contains(string(b), "CGSSessionScreenIsLocked = 1") {
            cmd = exec.Command(
                "/usr/bin/osascript",
                "-e",
                "display dialog \"Hello\"",
            )
            cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
            cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

            err = cmd.Run()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("err: ", err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works, but there is a problem. I need the dialog to be present forever until I press the "OK" button in the dialog when the screen is NOT off. With the solution, the dialog will be gone after a timeout. Are there any better workaround? Otherwise, i have to give a very big timeout value which is not very ideal. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sure there's a solution. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Take your time. ^_^

Comment: It seems the problem is specifically with `display dialog` I have updated the code with a second example which checks if the screen is locked before trying to call display dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code and time. I didn't realize this problem only happens to osascript before. Now, I am using `cmd := exec.Command(\`/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome\`, "-new-window", "/path/hello.html")` and so far so good. I think I will use browser for now. :)

Comment: Btw, I have upvoted and marked your answer as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `&` at the end of your command which will cause the program to run in the background.

```
 for {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/osascript", "-e", `display dialog "hello" with title "hello"`, "&")
    err := cmd.Run()
}
```